# Python kivy, how to use __init__ for classes with screen manager?

Tags: python, kivy, attributes, screen, init

I want to get instances of the attributes in each class, such as the users password and email, but I also want to be able to get the add_widget to come up with only the name, yet:
Here is my code so far

```
from kivy.uix import Screen, ScreenManager
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
sm = WindowManager()
```

In login window

```
class LoginWindow(Popups, Screen, FloatLayout, BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, email, password, checkBox, **kwargs):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.checkBox = checkBox
        super(self, **kwargs).__init__()
        self.name = "login"
```

And in main app window

```
sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name="login"))

#actual phone app class
class PhoneAssistantApp(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self).__init__()

    def build(self):
        if LoginWindow.checkBox == True:
            sm.current = "main"
        else:
            sm.current = "login" #user sent to login page whenever program is ran
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PhoneAssistantApp().run()
```

But it comes up with error:

```
line 352, in <module>
     sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name="login"))
 TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'email', 'password', and 'checkBox'
```

My login window in my kv file is simply:

```
<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login" #name used to know where to send
    email: email #links to object property in py file class
    password: password #links to object property in py file class
    checkBox: checkBox #links to boolean property in py file class
```

I believe the error is in my main program, as I'm trying to figure out how to fit both the attributes instances in with the kivy.

First I had my sm.add_widget and classes names in the App class, like

```
class PhoneAssistantApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(self, **kwargs).__init__()
        self.screens = ((LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="Create))
        self.sm = ScreenManager()

    def build(self):
        for screen in self.screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screens)
        if LoginWindow.checkBox == True:
            self.sm.current = "main"
        else:
            self.sm.current = "login" #user sent to login page whenever program is ran
        return self.sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PhoneAssistantApp().run()
```

And

```
class PhoneAssistantApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(self, **kwargs).__init__()
        self.screens = ((LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="Create))

    def build(self):
        for screen in self.screens:
            sm.add_widget(screens)
        if LoginWindow.checkBox == True:
            sm.current = "main"
        else:
            sm.current = "login" #user sent to login page whenever program is ran
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PhoneAssistantApp().run()
```

Yet taking it away didn't get rid of the problem. In addition, getting rid of the **kwargs likely didn't help much either.
It worked fine until I added the **init** into the classes.
I'm using visual studio code, where before I added the **init** hovering over name in above would display 'name=[literal]"login', yet now only displays 'name = "any"'
However, when hovering over name in the login class in my new code, it also returned 'name = [literal]login'.
Rather, I want to be able to use the name without having to indent the other attributes into my sm.add_widget.
While I did try putting the attributes in to see what would work, I tended to put:

```
sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name="login", email=LoginWindow.email, password=LoginWindow.password, checkBox=LoginWindow.checkBox))
```

As I simply wanted the instances of the attributes, but I don't think that's what I should do as it only got me error.

```
line 352, in <module>
     sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name="login", email=LoginWindow.email, password=LoginWindow.password, checkBox=LoginWindow.checkBox))
 AttributeError: type object 'LoginWindow' has no attribute 'email'
```

Thanks to anyone who'd be able to help out.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a method as you have:

```
def __init__(self, email, password, checkBox, **kwargs):
```

all those arguments are required whenever an instance of `LoginWindow` is created. Your code:

```
sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name="login"))
```

does not provide those required arguments, thus you get that error. You can instead use optional arguments by using keywords. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).